# What exact packages do I need to update inorder to upgrade the kernel?

Tags: kernel

https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3540-1/ ...............I am following this link to upgrade my kernel for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

need help what is the exact kernel version do i need to update to

I am confused between linux-image-generic 4.4.0.112.118 and linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic 4.4.0-112.135 .............these are the 2 kernel versions mentioned on the URL

which one should I update my server to

Current Kernel Version on my OS is

```
# dpkg -l|grep linux-image 

ii linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic 4.4.0-112.135 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP 
ii linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP 
ii linux-image-virtual 4.4.0.112.118 amd64 This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image. 


# uname -r 

4.4.0-59-generic 

# uname -a 

Linux ecs-nidhi-u16 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

root@ecs-nidhi-u16:~# dpkg -l|grep -iE "kernel" 
ii dmeventd 2:1.02.110-1ubuntu10 amd64 Linux Kernel Device Mapper event daemon 
ii dmsetup 2:1.02.110-1ubuntu10 amd64 Linux Kernel Device Mapper userspace library 
ii kmod 22-1ubuntu4 amd64 tools for managing Linux kernel modules 
ii libdevmapper-event1.02.1:amd64 2:1.02.110-1ubuntu10 amd64 Linux Kernel Device Mapper event support library 
ii libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 2:1.02.110-1ubuntu10 amd64 Linux Kernel Device Mapper userspace library 
ii libdrm2:amd64 2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- runtime 
ii linux-headers-4.4.0-112 4.4.0-112.135 all Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0 
ii linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic 4.4.0-112.135 amd64 Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP 
ii linux-headers-4.4.0-59 4.4.0-59.80 all Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0 
ii linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP 
ii linux-headers-generic 4.4.0.112.118 amd64 Generic Linux kernel headers 
ii linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic 4.4.0-112.135 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP 
ii linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP 
ii linux-image-virtual 4.4.0.112.118 amd64 This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image. 
ii linux-virtual 4.4.0.112.118 amd64 Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers 
ii rsyslog 8.16.0-1ubuntu3 amd64 reliable system and kernel logging daemon 
root@ecs-nidhi-u16:~#
```

Please help me ASAP what exact packages do I need to update inorder to upgrade the kernel

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using the ordinary -generic kernel instead of an architecture-specific kernel, use 135 or higher.

Your output indicates that you already have 135 installed. Simply reboot into the new kernel using GRUB.

[How to get to the GRUB menu at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/19626)